# Obtain positions of multiple characters simultaneously from a list in R

Tags: r

My data structure is as follows:

```
m 
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "k" "k" "k" "l"
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "g" "h" "k" "k" "k" "l" "g"
[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "g" "h" "h" "h" "k" "l" "h"
```

I want to find positions of each unique characters simultaneously. Individually I can obtain positions of each character using the following code:

```
t<-list()
for (i in 1:length(m)){
for (j in m[[i]][[1]]){
if (j=="k"){
t[[i]]<-grep(j,m[[i]][[1]],fixed=TRUE)}}}
```

The result I obtain is as follows:

```
t
[[1]]
[1] 4 5 6
[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5
[[3]]
[1] 5
```

There are 4 unique characters in list m and I will get 4 lists with positions of unique characters using my code but I have to manually enter each character into the loop. I need a single code which will calculate positions for all the 
unique characters simultaneously.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `dput(m)` and paste it in here.

Comment: I haven't put the expected output because I am not able to visualize what the expected output will look like in R. Generally I want it like this: "k" [[1]] [1] 4 5 6 [[2]] [1] 3 4 5 [[3]] [1] 5, "h" [[1]] [1] 3 [[2]] [1] 2 [[3]] [1] 2 3 4 7, "g" [[1]] [1] 1 2 [[2]] [1] 1 7 [[3]] [1] 1 ,"l"  [[1]] [1] 7 [[2]] [1] 6 [[3]] [1] 6

Comment: list(list(c("g", "g", "h", "k", "k", "k", "l")), list(c("g", 
"h", "k", "k", "k", "l", "g")), list(c("g", "h", "h", "h", "k", 
"l", "h")))

Answer (score 1):

The vectors in your list seem all to be of equal length (if not this could be adjusted by making them equal length). I would first restructure the data:

```
m <- list(list(c("g", "g", "h", "k", "k", "k", "l")),
          list(c("g", "h", "k", "k", "k", "l", "g")))

m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(m, "[[", 1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,] "g"  "g"  "h"  "k"  "k"  "k"  "l" 
#[2,] "g"  "h"  "k"  "k"  "k"  "l"  "g"
```

Then you can use `outer` to make all comparisons at once:

```
res <- which(outer(m, unique(c(m)), "=="), arr.ind = TRUE)
res <- as.data.frame(res)
res$dim3 <- factor(res$dim3, labels = unique(c(m)))
names(res) <- c("list_element", "vector_element", "letter")

#check
res[res$letter == "k" & res$list_element == 1, "vector_element"]
[1] 4 5 6
```

This solution won't work well if your data is huge.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a double loop with `lapply` where we check position using `which` for each `unique` value in `m`

```
lst <- lapply(unique(unlist(m)), function(x) 
              lapply(m, function(y) which(x == y[[1]])))
lst

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 7

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] 1


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] 2 3 4 7
......
```

To identify which values represent which character we can name the `list`

```
names(lst) <- unique(unlist(m))

lst
#$g
#$g[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#$g[[2]]
#[1] 1 7

#$g[[3]]
#[1] 1

...
```

Comment: posted a solution - realised it was identical to yours - deleted mine.